# Any finite measure space can be written as finite disjoint union of measurable set with arbitrarily small measure

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-sets

$(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ be a finite measure space then is the following true ?

> For every $\delta>0$, $X$ is finite disjoint union of measurable sets such that the measure of the set(s) are less or equal to $\delta$.

I tried this and could figure out a proof for lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$. For general case I couldn't.

**Context:** I was trying to prove the converse part of Proposition 4.23 given in the image, which will follow from Lemma 4.22 given there but I couldn't prove the lemma.

[image: I am talking about the lemma]

Comment: Consider a finite measure space where $X$ consists of a single point.

Comment: $\delta_0$. Perhaps if the measure is atom free?

Comment: @copper.hat I don't think atom-free is enough. For example a free ultrafilter gives an atom-free measure where every set has measure $1$ or $0$.

Comment: @Daron Does that work for countably additive measures? (Certainly out of my comfort zone :-).)

Comment: Thanks. Post edited, have a look. I shall be grateful if you could help me with this problem @Daron

Comment: Thanks. Post edited, have a look. I shall be grateful if you could help me with this problem @LorenzoNajt

Comment: Thanks. Post edited, have a look. I shall be grateful if you could help me with this problem@copper.hat

Comment: @Noobmathematician Please open a new question if you want to modify this one.

Comment: @copper.hat You're right. An ultrafilter only gives a countably additive (not) measure. To get a full measure we need a *countably* complete untrafilter. I believe the existence of those guys is independent of ZFC. So all ultrafilters get you is "not no in ZFC". Probably there's a simpler counterexample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**False**

For example take $X =\{1,2\}$ with each element having measure $1/2$.  Then every nonempty set has measure $1/2$ or $1$ and so the claim fails for $\delta=1/4$.

Comment: Thanks. Post edited, have a look. I shall be grateful if you could help me with this problem

Comment: Even with the new edit, this answer still stand as a counterexample. Your Lemma 4.22 is just wrong as stated. In any case, please ask a new question (and be specific about which measure you are using). @Noobmathematician